# ngCordova imagePicker plugin error: Cannot read property 'getPictures' of undefined

Tags: ngcordova

I have installed the imagePicker plugin, as described in:

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/imagePicker/

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
//See: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/imagePicker/


  var imagePickerOptions = {
        maximumImagesCount: 10,
        width: 800,
        height: 800,
        quality: 80
    };

$scope.pickImage = function () {
    $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(imagePickerOptions).then(function (imageData) {
        for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++) {
            $scope.registration.imgSrc = imageData[i];
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    $scope.registerform.show();
};
```

While debugging the code, I can see that $cordovaImagePicker is correctly injected:

[image: Screen-shot 1 (value)]

Only, when I call:

$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(imagePickerOptions)
I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPictures' of undefined":

[image: screen-shot 2 (error)]

How can I fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I have the same problem with other plugins, notably: de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification and https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin.git

Comment: Looks like you're using ripple emulator and I believe it only works on a device.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an intrinsic problem of the plugin itself: WP is not supported (yet).
This is documented at the imagePicker page http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/imagePicker/ (see icons of supported systems at the top-right angle of the page).